# A static double pointer Vs A reference to a single static pointer

Tags: c, pointers

Let say I want to use a library function that has this signature :

```
void example(int **temp);
```

I get a segmentation fault when I pass **a static double-pointer**:

```
int main(){
    int **x; 
    example(x);
}
```

However, I don't get any error when I pass **a reference to a single-pointer**:

```
int main(){
    int *x; 
    example(&x);
}
```

What is the difference between these two types of pointers and when do I know which to use?

Comment: What does "example" do?

Comment: Let say it is a C standard library function. I am trying to use this function : 
`pcap_next_ex(.... , ....,const u_char **pkt_data);` If the call succeeds, pkt_data  argument is set to point to the data in the packet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So many problem in this example case.

Starting from the fact that a pointer has to been initialized, or you have an undefined behavior. In fact if not initialized it points to a garbage address.

now in the first case you have:

```
int **x;
```

that is

*x = address of a pointer that points to an address that points to an int*. To better explain **x->y->int**. But in your case you only instantiate the first pointer x and ever not initialized. So y and the int doesn't have memory allocated and doesn't exist.
A good way to do this could be this:

```
int **x = (int **)malloc(sizeof (int*)); // allocate and initialize memory for x
*x = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int)); // allocate the memory for the int and initialize the so called "y"
```

In the second case you have:

```
int *x;
```

But you also in this case you don't initializes the pointer. So you have x that has a garbage address. So the best way could be this:

```
int *x = (int *)malloc(sizeof (int));
```

Then in the call of the function example you do the right thing giving the reference of the pointer x to the function.

Please, pay attention, the function that takes pointer to pointer has parameter need to modify the address of the pointer final value in the major of the case. So the initialization is fundamental.

Answer (score 0):

Since the function `example` return type is `void` for it to operate on `temp` and have those changes seen back in the caller, it expects the *address of* a pointer so it can dereference the double-pointer and work on `*temp` within `example`. When you declare `int **x;` you pass `x` by value which is uninitialized and if then dereferenced in `example` likely leads to a SegFault.

However, when you declare `int *x;` and then pass the address of `x` to `example` (e.g. `example (&x)`, then within `example` the dereference of `*x` (e.g. `*temp`) provides the original address of `x` back in the calling function allowing you to operate on `*temp` within `example` just as you would operate on `x` back in the calling function.

That is about as concrete an example as I can give based on what is provided in the question.

Also remember that in C all you have is *pass-by-value*, there are no *references*. In the first case with `int **x;` you pass the value held by `x` (which is uninitialized). In the second case with `int *x;` you pass the *address of `x` by value -- and that address is always set.

A short example may help:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void example (int **temp)
{
    *temp = malloc (sizeof **temp);
    **temp = 5;
}

int main (void) {

    // int **x = NULL;  /* value of temp will be NULL */
    int *y = NULL;      /* value of temp will be address of pointer y */

    // example (x);     /* segfault - dereferences NULL in example */
    example (&y);       /* OK */

    printf ("*y: %d\n", *y);

    free (y);
}
```

Note above, if `example (x)` is called, `temp` is a copy of `x` with its very own and very different address. With `example (&y)`, `temp` holds the address of the pointer `y`, so dereferencing `temp` (e.g. `*temp`) provides the original address for pointer `y` back in `main()` allowing a block of memory to be assigned to the original pointer and a value stored in that block of memory that is available in `main()` on the return of `example`.

Answer (score 0):

The difference between those two:

```
int **x0;
int *y;
int **x1 = &y;
```

is that the `X0` is an unitialized pointer and `X1` is referencing the theisting pointer `y`